# 3x8 to 1x8 (with expansion to 1x10/1x11 in the future)

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, chainring

I plan on converting my MTB fron 3x8 to 1x8.

I plan on leaving the rear derailleur as it is, or I would prefer not to upgrade it to save money.

My current crankset is a 3x8 square taper crank, I have yet to measure the bottom bracket but it'll be probably a 68 or a 73 shell, with standard  BSA/ISO threading.

Part list **installed**:

Crankset:

https://www.paul-lange.de/shop/de/shimano/alivio-acera-altus-7-8-fach/kurbelgarnitur-altus-trekking-fc-m311-vierkant-78-fach.html

Bottom Bracket:

https://www.paul-lange.de/shop/de/shimano/innenlager/innenlager-bb-un26-vierkant-bsa.html

Part list to **purchase**:

https://www.bike24.de/1.php?content=8;product=164399;menu=1000,2,88;mid[70]=1;pgc[7296][7301]=1;orderby=2

https://www.bike24.de/1.php?content=8;product=7192;menu=1000,2,81;mid[77]=1;mid[282]=1;mid[170]=1;pgc[10624][10627]=1;orderby=2

---

**My question's/troubles:**

BSA threading is universal/standardized right ?

If I purchase a 1x10 crank or a  1x11 crank for example I could install it on 1x8 setup right ?

What compatability issues should  I look out for ?

Are the listed parts compatible with each other ?

Comment: If you're going 1 x 11 that's likely a new wheel

Comment: @batman, aren't MTB 11 speed cassettes the same width?

Comment: either way, it is not my current wish but only something id like to keep an eye out in the future, if thatdescribes it better

Comment: MTB 11 is the same. Road 11 needs longer freehub splines.

Comment: Shimano 11 cassette fits onto a 10 speed body, SRAM 11 needs a SRAm XD Body.

Comment: Have you done the numbers at http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gears/ to see how your range will be affected ?  I've got a 1x8 and want to go up to a 2x or 3x8 for more gearing range, both top and bottom end.

Comment: I am aware that I'll lose a fair share of gear range, but I have ridden the past  couple of weeks without much need for the extra gears and I'm ready to sacrifice them for the simplicity in return

Comment: @mattnz Kind of. It's true that SRAM is pushing XD hard, but in practice many 11 speed SRAM mountain bikes have normal splined hubs and either the SRAM PG-1130 11-42 cassette or somebody else's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It's unclear if you mean versus other standards, or if there are
   different kinds of BSC/ISO ([BSA is kind of a misnomer](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_bo-z.html#bsa), and in
   my opinion it's clearer just to call it all ISO, because that's the
   standard that current examples are actually made to). Some road
   bikes are still made with Italian, but only a couple brands, and
   bottom brackets can still be had for all the old national sizes.
   Other than that, yes ISO is the only threaded standard left. Each ISO
   BB is made for a certain shell width, or widths in the case of the common 68/73/e-type ones that come with 2.5mm spacers you use as needed, but there aren't shell
   interface differences within ISO beyond that.
2. Yes, no problem.
3. Chain retention tends to be acceptable with just a narrow-wide ring and nothing else helping it, but it's something I'd be looking at when test riding the new setup. Of all the many rear derailers in the world, you could probably come up with some that didn't pull on the chain adequately. It's also good practice to start a new chainring out with at least a new chain and ideally also a new cassette. (This is now less true of the cassette since suddenly it's much more common for people to have extremely expensive ones.) You could skimp on it if they're still pretty fresh, but the idea is that minimizing wear on the ring tends to save more money ultimately. Worn chains can bring a new chainring to their level of wear fairly rapidly.

   - Chainline is also something one should look at when putting a 1x or 
     any other drivetrain together, although it's perennially overlooked 
     and so parts manufacturers do what they can to make it work out okay
     passively. Buying a dedicated 1x mountain crank with 49mm chainline 
     such as the one you link to and putting it on a normal 135 8/9/10
     rear (which wants a chainline somewhere around there) puts you in the camp of not
     having to worry about it. Other setups create some hoops to jump
     through.
4. Yes, presuming you get the correct version of the BB. (The BSA 68/73 unless it's got an 83 or 100mm shell.) You need an external BB cup tool.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll accept this answer next morning (if no better answer will appear :) ), I appreciate your help